# Why can the compiler not optimize floating point addition with 0?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compilation, compiler-optimization

I have four identity functions which do essentially nothing. Only multiplication with `1` could be optimized by clang to a single `ret` statement.

```cpp
float id0(float x) {
    return x + 1 - 1;
}

float id1(float x) {
    return x + 0;
}

float id2(float x) {
    return x * 2 / 2;
}

float id3(float x) {
    return x * 1;
}
```

And the following compiler output is: (clang 10, at -O3)

```
.LCPI0_0:
        .long   1065353216              # float 1
.LCPI0_1:
        .long   3212836864              # float -1
id0(float):                                # @id0(float)
        addss   xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]
        addss   xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1]
        ret
id1(float):                                # @id1(float)
        xorps   xmm1, xmm1
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        ret
.LCPI2_0:
        .long   1056964608              # float 0.5
id2(float):                                # @id2(float)
        addss   xmm0, xmm0
        mulss   xmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI2_0]
        ret
id3(float):                                # @id3(float)
        ret
```

I can understand why `id0` and `id2` can't be optimized. They increase the value which could then turn into positive infinity and the second operation would not change it back.

But why can't `id1` be optimized? Additon with infinity would yield infinity, addition with any regular number would yield that number and addition with `NaN` would yield `NaN`. So why is it not a "true" identity operation like `* 1`.

[Example with Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TsfVWY)

Comment: This is a really good question. I don't understand why I'm the only upvoter.

Comment: Not applicable to these specific examples, but please keep in mind that these results are only guaranteed by _operator associativity_. That is for example, the additive operators + and - are guaranteed to evaluate left-to-right. Therefore the implicit conversion to float happens where it should, possibly by luck(?). `x + 1 - 1` has a different meaning than `1 - 1 + x` . The former is equivalent to `(x + (float)1) - (float)1` and the latter to `(float)((int)1 - (int)1) + x;`. To avoid such bugs, use float constants `1.0f`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

IEEE 754 floating-point numbers have two zero values, one negative, one positive. When added together, the result is the positive one.

So `id1(-0.f)` is `0.f`, not `-0.f`.
Note that `id1(-0.f) == -0.f` because `0.f == -0.f`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/N2Y9Lt)

Also, note that compiling with `-ffast-math` in GCC does make the optimization and changes the result.

Comment: Damn, you were faster. Here a [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GE9Mqt) for illustration.

Comment: Nicely written. I was starting to write an answer, but you finished first because you expressed the situation more cleanly.

Answer (score 8):

> "I have four identity functions which do essentially nothing."

That's not true.

For floating-point numbers `x + 1 - 1` is not equal `x + 0`, it is equal `(x + 1) - 1`. So if you have e.g. a very small `x` then you will lose that very small portion in the `x + 1` step, and the compiler can't know if that was your intent or not.

And in the case of `x * 2 / 2`, the `x * 2` might not be exact either, due to floating-point precision, so you have a similar case here, the compiler does not know if you for some reason want to change the value of `x` in that manner.

So these would be equal:

```
float id0(float x) {
    return x + (1. - 1.);
}

float id1(float x) {
    return x + 0;
}
```

And these would be equal:

```
float id2(float x) {
    return x * (2. / 2.);
}

float id3(float x) {
    return x * 1;
}
```

The desired behavior could for sure be defined in another way. But as already mentioned by [Nelfeal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129382/1960455) this optimization has to be explicitly activated using `-ffast-math`

> Enable fast-math mode. This option lets the compiler make aggressive, potentially-lossy assumptions about floating-point math. These include:
>
> - Floating-point math obeys regular algebraic rules for real numbers (e.g. + and * are associative, x/y == x * (1/y), and (a + b) * c == a * c + b * c),
> - Operands to floating-point operations are not equal to NaN and Inf, and
> - +0 and -0 are interchangeable.

`fast-math` is for clang and gcc a collection of flags (here the one listed by clang):

> - -fno-honor-infinities
> - -fno-honor-nans
> - -fno-math-errno
> - -ffinite-math
> - -fassociative-math
> - -freciprocal-math
> - -fno-signed-zeros
> - -fno-trapping-math
> - -ffp-contract=fast

Comment: `x * 2` might not be exact, but not because of floating point precision, rather because of its range: `x * 2` might produce an infinity if `x` is too large. This is less likely to occur for `x * 2.` as `2.` has type `double` and `double` usually has a larger range than `float`.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [floating-number-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/) web page, more about [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754), the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

```
float id1(float x) {
    return x + 0;
}
```

If `x` happens to be a signaling [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), your `id1` might even not return (and probably *should not* return).

If `x` is a quiet NaN, then `id1(x) != x` since `NaN != NaN` (at least `NaN == NaN` should be false).

In *some* cases, you want costly [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). Then consider using [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).

PS. Floating point numbers can give you nightmares or a PhD, at your choice. They sometimes [kill people](http://ta.twi.tudelft.nl/users/vuik/wi211/disasters.html) or at least make huge financial disasters (e.g. a loss of several hundred millions US$ or €).

Comment: Interesting links - Especially the "kill people" link I have to bookmark. Here is another related one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: *They sometimes kill people or at least make huge financial disasters (e.g. a loss of several hundred millions US$ or €)* This sounds like a personal experience, (ça sent le vécu), did you participate in the investigation on the failure of the [first Ariane 5 lauch](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vol_501_d%27Ariane_5)?

Comment: If `x` is a quiet NaN, returning `x` still produces `id1(x) != x`. The real issue is negative zero where `1 / id1(x) != 1 / x`

Comment: @chrqlie: the lab I am working at in CEA LIST did have access to Ariane 5 related documentation, but I personally didn't.