# Trouble with large numbers while using <iomanip> larger in cpp

Tags: c++

While sorting and displaying big numbers you usually end up displaying the large numbers in enotation. I was trying to display the whole number by using the `<iomanip>` library in cpp and it fails for very large numbers.

```
 //big sorting
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    #include<iomanip>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        double arr[n];
        for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
            cin>>arr[i];

        sort(arr, arr+n);
        cout<<fixed<<setprecision(0);
        for (int i = 0;i < n; i++)
            cout<<arr[i]<<endl; 
    }
```

Input:

```
31415926535897932384626433832795
1
3
10
3
5
```

Expected output:

```
1
3
3
5
10
31415926535897932384626433832795
```

Actual output:

```
1
3
3
5
10
31415926535897933290036940242944
```

The last digit is getting messed up.

Answer (score 1):

The double type precision is only 15 decimal digits, so very large whole numbers can't be expressed in double type without loss of precison.

Comment: could you also give me a solution like should I use long long int or something?

Comment: Well, there are multiple possible solutions depending on what is your intention. You need to set the requirement - i.e. answer questions like: (a) how large can your numbers be? (b) are the numbers necessarily whole numbers or can be others? (c) If all numbers are integers - can they be negative?

Comment: I'm sorry I should've specified that in the question.

Comment: 1=<n<= 2*10(^5)  and each number is a positive nnumber

Comment: The particular number in your example `31415926535897932384626433832795` is larger than what 64 bit unsigned integer could fit, so `long long` won't be enough. It could fit in 128 bit integer though, but if you consider higher numbers it won't help. Not sure I read your notation correct - 2*10^5 means 20000? Or is it 2 to the power of 100000? If 20000 then why the number in your examples is much larger than that?

Comment: n is just the size of the array

Comment: what about the numbers themselves?

Comment: If you read the first sentence there carefully - you can see that they specify that each number is between 1 and 10^6 digits (so numbers can be ridiculously large). This is a very unusual thing in most programming tasks - so you probably want to specify it when asking anyone on how to handle such numbers (here or anywhere else). For this task there are many possible solutions, for example: (a) use Python which can handle arbitrary big integers, (b) represent numbers as strings of digits.

Comment: @KrishnnaSarrdah  *n is just the size of the array* -- First this, `double arr[n];` is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes known at compile time, not runtime.  Use `std::vector<double> arr(n);` instead.  Second, if `n` was large, you risk exhausting the stack memory using `double arr[n]`.  You shouldn't use the fake C++ in declaring arrays -- it is not valid C++ syntax, and can only cause more issues than you may think it solves.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - after you pointed out that thing I couldn't believe this compiles. Then I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/array-size-at-run-time-without-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed. This was very surprising to me. C++ holds a lot of secrets...

Answer (score 1):

#### Read more [about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), perhaps the C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf).

Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler, e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (invoked as `g++`) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/) (invoked as `clang++`). Read of course a [good C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), since ***C++* is a very difficult programming language**. Use C++ standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

Large numbers does not fit natively in a computer memory (or in its registers). For example, with C++ code compiled by [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) on Linux/x86-64, an `int` has just 32 bits.

Consider using [arbitrary precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). You might be interested by [GMPlib](https://gmplib.org/).

Floating point numbers are weird. Be sure to read the famous [floating-point-gui.de](https://floating-point-gui.de/) website, and see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62129619/841108) answer.

> `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

**is wrong** since non-standard. Take the habit of `#include`-ing only headers needed by your [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit), except if you use [pre-compiled headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html).

Take some time to read more about [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) and [arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic). Some notion of [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) is incredibly useful when programming: a lot of computers are computing modulo 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>.

Study for inspiration the C++ source code of existing [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software (e.g. on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/), including [FLTK](https://www.fltk.org/)). If you use Linux, its [fish-shell](https://fishshell.com/) has a nice C++ code. You could even glance inside the source code of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and of [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), both being nice C++ open source compilers.

In practice, read also about [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) ([free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) coded in C) or [ninja](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) (open source [tool coded](https://ninja-build.org/) in C++).

Don't forget to use a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (I recommend [git](https://git-scm.com/)).

#### Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Enable all warnings and debug info when compiling your C++ code ([with GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html), use  `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`).

#### Read of course the documentation of your favorite debugger.

I am a happy user of [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/).

Consider using [static program analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) tools such as the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) or [Frama-C++](https://frama-c.com/).

Comment: You might want to add `-pedantic` flag in the list of suggested compiler options. Without it the compiler won't catch the issue with declaring `double arr[n]` with `n` unknown at compile time.